# TextView setText taking a long time to render text

Tags: android

I'm working with an Android App that is setting some crazy texts in the textviews 390892 characters or more, the app is not crashing (At least not on my devices). However, is taking between 2 - 3 seconds to render the text.

Is there a way to set the text in the textview from another thread different to the ui-thread?

Comment: No. Moreover, that will not help with rendering speed. Moreover, the screen cannot show 390892 characters at once, except at impossible-to-read font sizes. Use a `RecyclerView` instead of some big `TextView` in an equally big `ScrollView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Great solution. Split your text into logical blocks of reasonable size and put them into a RecyclerView. Only the parts that are needed at the moment will be rendered and you will notice no lag.

Comment: If i may ask,  why do you want to load 390892 characters in an EditText. Can you explain more why you ned to do this, then we can suggest other better way of achieving what you want done.

Comment: Actually, I was just thinking in diving it but never thought in the RecyclerView. Sounds like a good idea guys

Comment: That is what I'm getting from the DB and that comes from a server, to be honest I don't know why I'm getting those huge texts. the app is something like flipboard but it seems I'm receiving a book instead of an article